# How to choose a perfect color for a simple personal portfolio?

Tags: colors, background-color, color-picker

---

I wanted to make a simple portfolio website. But I don't > understand about color. What color can be used? I tried make some > black and white color combination but I don't understand about others > color combination

Answer (score 1):

The colors on your site's homepage can have a profound impact on the visitor, but only if you know how to use them. What color combinations you use to design your portfolio page will depend on what kind of industry you will be working in?

For instance, there is a reason why the logos and sites of most fast food makers (from MacDonalds to Pizza-hut) have liberal usage of Yellow and Red colors. You see, Red and Yellow being warm colors, have a very stimulating effect subconsciously. Research has shown that yellow is known to affect your hunger/appetite.

Similarly, Banks, Insurance and Legal services make use of White, Blue and Green colors. These are cold colors and have the exact opposite effect of calming you down.

So, keeping [Color Psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_psychology) in mind, you have to carefully choose a primary color, a secondary color to contrast it, and finally an accent color. Keep yourself in the shoes of your site's audience, and you should have no problems selecting them!

Comment: Thank you very much. But I also don't understand about color combination. Like background color,or font color. What about those combination. Light or Deep.

Comment: @KhadezatulKobra - As I said, you will have to choose a primary color and secondary color for your site. You can use the primary color for fonts, carousels, borders, etc. that form the major display areas. The secondary color is used to create some contrast, so it should be the opposite of primary color and generally used in backgrounds. For instance, if you choose yellow font color, then black background should combine with it nicely (see Apress site for example). Instead of theorizing, I suggest you get practical and start designing some pages in HTML/CSS! All this comes through practice.

Comment: please can you tell me,Your answers is cleared my concept but why people gave me down-vote.  I know they know lots but I am new in here And I am starting to learn in this sector.

Comment: @KhadezatulKobra - Don't takes the downvotes personally, they always come here. You see, SO has certain standards with regard to what kind of questions you can ask, and what amount of research you have to perform. You can read them on the [site meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/). But since you are new here, people should not have down-voted your question, but rather explained this fact.

Comment: Thank you very much. But some people are always discouraged us. Its very bad. I really appreciate your help. In future if i query any question please answer. Thank you